# mvc4 add where clause when retrieve json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to retrieve json from my controller to my model

the controller will make a retrive for the data from database then transfer it to json

i tried this

```
    return this.Json(
              new
              {
                  Result = (from obj in db.Parkings select new { ID = obj.ID, Name = obj.note })
              }
              , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
           );
```

it works perfectly.

now i want to edit that in order to add a `where` to the retrival operation.

what i mean is:

#### i dont want retrieve all the parking, but i want to retrive the parking  that buildingID equal to 1

i tried google but i couldnt disvoer the solution my self

Comment: Did you read [Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397927.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, add your where method after your dbset. As follows:

```
return this.Json(
          new
          {
              Result = (from obj in db.Parkings
                                      .Where(p => p.BuildingId == myBuildingId)
                        select new
                        {
                            ID = obj.ID,
                            Name = obj.note
                        })
          }
          , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
       );
```

You can also use the following syntax:

```
    (from obj in db.Parkings 
          where obj.BuildingId == myBuildingId
          select new { ID = obj.ID, Name = obj.note })
          }
          , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
       );
```

I recommend taking a look at [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) and see the similar lambda syntax in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) for practicing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Result = Parkings.Where(x=> x.buildingID == 1).Select(new { ID = obj.ID, Name = obj.note });
```